# Installing Visual Studio 2012 for Windows phone on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2012

I've been trying to install Visual Studio **2012** for windows phone in my **windows 7** box. I know that is posible because this page says that the 2012 version is compatible: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compatibility but I get that I'm not running **Windows 8**

Anyone knows how to install VS2012 for windows phone in windows 7? Is it possible then?

Comment: The [Windows Phone SDK update for Windows Phone 7.8](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36474) works in Vista+, but [Windows Phone SDK 8.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471) works only in Win8 x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-phone#product-express-phone) (which is lead to directly from the top result for me googling for `visual studio 2012 for windows phone`),  **only the x64 versions of Windows 8 are supported.**

So going by that, it is not possible to install that version of Visual Studio on Windows 7.